# Irrational and complex roots of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, roots

I have been thinking about this for a while and am stumped. Suppose I have a monic  $n'$th order polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ given by

$$P(x) = x^n + c_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + c_nx + c_0$$.

Vieta's Formulas allow for a factorization over the roots $r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n$ where

$$x^n + c_{n - 1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + c_nx + c_0 = (x - r_n)(x - r_{n - 1})\cdots(x - r_1)$$

and the roots may be complex. Now suppose it is known that there is only one integer root and the degree is greater than 2. All other roots must then be complex, and the Conjugate Root Theorem states that if $r_l$ is a complex root of $P(x)$, then $\bar r_l$ is also a root of $P(x)$. Does it then follow that the degree must be odd since it is assumed there is only one integer root? I am asking because I am not sure if the Irrational Root Theorem applies for degree larger than $n = 2$ if a real root exists that is not an integer.

Comment: What about multiple roots?

Comment: @Randall, multiplicity of roots may be assumed.

Comment: So I can take something like $(x-1)(x-1)(x+i)(x-i)$?  Or are you counting the root of $1$ as contributing $2$ roots?  Is that "only one integer root"?

Comment: @Randall In this case, if one is the root, it may not be repeated since there is only one integer root.

Comment: Got it.  Just clarifying your hypotheses.

Comment: "All other roots must then be complex" is not true. Since e.g. $Q(x) := x^3-x+2$ has one irrational real and a pair of complex roots, $P(x)=x^4-x^2+2x = x \cdot Q(x)$ has one integer root but not all other roots are complex.